# How do I disable and re-enable a submit type button with a slider style checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently having some issue to figure how to disable and enable a submit type `button` with a slider `checkbox`.

```js
function check() {
    var ele = document.getElementsById('check');
    var flag = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].checked) {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag === 1) {
        document.getElementByClass('valider').disabled = "enabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementByClass('valider').disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

```css
 /* Button CSS */
 .valider {
     float: right;
     padding: 12px 20px;
     margin-top: 1%;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 2px solid white;
     border-radius: 4px;
     color: white;
     background-color: #24c238;
 }

 .valider:hover {
     border: 2px solid #24c238;
     color: #24c238;
     background-color: white;
 }

 .valider:disabled {
     cursor: default;
     border-color: #999;
     color: #999;
     background-color: #4d7d52;
 }

 /* Slider CSS */
 .switch {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 10px;
 }

 .switch input {
     opacity: 0;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
 }

 .slider {
     position: absolute;
     cursor: pointer;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: #ccc;
     -webkit-transition: .4s;
     transition: .4s;
 }

 .slider:before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     height: 26px;
     width: 26px;
     left: 4px;
     bottom: 4px;
     background-color: white;
     -webkit-transition: .4s;
     transition: .4s;
 }

 input:checked+.slider {
     background-color: #24c238;
 }

 input:focus+.slider {
     box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
 }

 input:checked+.slider:before {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
     -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
     transform: translateX(26px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="formulaire">
    <form action="./signCheck.php" method="GET">
        <h3>Inscrivez-vous</h3>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="nom"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Nom<text class="obligatoire">*</text></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="ex: Martin">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="prenom"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Prénom<text class="obligatoire">*</text></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="ex: Pierre">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="motDePasse"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i> Mot de Passe<text class="obligatoire">*</text></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="password" id="mdp" name="mdp" placeholder="Maximum 12 caractères" maxlength="12">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="motDePasse"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i> Confirmer Mot de Passe<text class="obligatoire">*</text></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="password" id="cMdp" name="cMdp" placeholder="************" maxlength="12">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="telephone"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> Téléphone<text class="obligatoire">*</text></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="ex: 0602215684" maxlength="10">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="mail"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Adresse email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="ex: monadressemail@mail.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="typeCompte"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Statut</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <select id="typeCompte" name="typeCompte">
                    <option value="S">Stagiaire</option>
                    <option value="P">Partenaire</option>
                    <option value="E">Employeur</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <div class="col25">
                <label for="confidential" style="font-size: 40%">En vous inscrivant, vous acceptez nos <a href="#">politiques de confidentialité</a></label>
                <label style="color: white; font-size: 40%;">* champs obligatoires</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col75">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="check()"><span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ligne">
                <button class="valider" id="submitbtn" type="submit" formaction="./signCheck" formmethod="get" disabled>
                    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> S'inscrire
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div style="font-size: 50%">Déjà un compte ? <a href="connexion">Connectez-vous</a></div>
</div>
```

But nothing works, I managed easily to disable initially the button, but I didn't success to enable it back.

Have any advice to help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` is a boolean attribute. Thus, as long as an HTMLElement has the disabled attribute set (to whatever value except `false`) it's disabled. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) To reenable the element you have to entirely remove the `disabled` attribute or set it explicitely to `false`

Furthermore, as all the elements used for that switching have id, it's easier to find them by this id instead of a classname, because that won't return a list of elements, but just a single element.

```
function check() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('check');

    if (ele.checked) {
        document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. But I'm afraid it doesn't due to the fact the button is type=submit. I saw that some using `disabled="disabled"` so I don't know.

Comment: `getElementByClass()` is not a function, `getElementsByClass()` is the correct name of the function and it returns a collection of elements therefore you have to select the one you need before being able to access its attributes.

Comment: @CreamyVelvet No, it perfectly works also with `type=submit`. I was just concentrating too much on the issue with `disabled` so I didn't pay attention to the other syntax issues

Comment: @secan Actually, the really correct function name is `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: I updated the code, I added the whole page plus the page that use the form

Comment: @derpirscher, yes, you're right; my attention got caught by Element/Elements and I missed that bit. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to change your check function like the following thing:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        var ele = document.getElementById('check');
        var flag = 0;
        if (ele.checked) {
            flag = 1;
        }else{
            flag = 0;
                   }
        if (flag == 1) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('valider')[0].disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('valider')[0].disabled = false;
        }
    } 
    </script>
```

and change too in html the following line:

```
<button class="valider" type="submit" formaction="./signCheck" formmethod="get" disabled><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> S'inscrire</button>
```

disabled with not equal.

Hope that could help you!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I really appreciate. However, your solution didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: I edited it, if you want to try it another time @CreamyVelvet

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code:

#### HTML

You have an extra closing double-quote for the button `class` attribute:

```html
<button class="valider"" type="submit" formaction="./signCheck" formmethod="get" disabled><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> S'inscrire</button>
```

should be:

```html
<button class="valider" type="submit" formaction="./signCheck" formmethod="get" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> S'inscrire</button>
```

#### JS

1. The function name is `getElementById()`, not `getElementsById()` (with an 's'):

```js
var ele = document.getElementsById('check');
```

should be:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('check');
```

2. `getElementById()` returns a single element, therefore the entire block

```js
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i ++) {
  if (ele[i].checked) {
    flag = 1;
  }
}
```

does not make sense.

3. because of point (2), the check `if (flag === 1)` does not make sense (nor it works as you intended)

```js
if (flag === 1)
```

should be:

```js
if (ele.checked)
```

4. the function is `getElementsByClassName()` (with an 's'), not `getElementByClass()` and returns a collection. Anyway, as you should have only one submit buttom for each form, it would make more sense to assign an `id` to it and target it with `getElementById()`.
5. `disabled` is a boolean attribute so you should not change it from "disabled" to "enabled" but you should add or remove it.

```js
document.getElementByClass('valider').disabled = "enabled";
```

and

```js
document.getElementByClass('valider').disabled = "disabled";
```

should be:

```js
document.getElementById('submitbtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
```

and

```js
document.getElementById('submitbtn').setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

Putting everything together, you get:

```js
function check() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('check');

  if (ele.checked) {
    document.getElementById('submitbtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('submitbtn').setAttribute("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Button CSS */

.valider {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #24c238;
}

.valider:hover {
  border: 2px solid #24c238;
  color: #24c238;
  background-color: white;
}

.valider:disabled {
  cursor: default;
  border-color: #999;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #4d7d52;
}


/* Slider CSS */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #24c238;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col75">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onclick="check()"><span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="ligne">
  <button class="valider" id="submitbtn" type="submit" formaction="./signCheck" formmethod="get" disabled>
    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> S'inscrire
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: First at all, thanks for making me noticing my errors, I didn't see them. Also, I tried your code, and it still didn't work. Does Chrom blocks something ?

Comment: What you mean with "*it still didn't work*"? Do you not see it working in the snippet here or it does not work when you copy it into your code?

Comment: It doesn't in my code, so maybe it's due to something else in my code, like another script that makes conflict or something else

Comment: Maybe, but it is impossible to tell without seeing the entire code

Comment: I'll try to provide it tomorrow. Though I'm not sure how to give whole files. .

Comment: You do not need to provide the entire website, you just need to share the relevant code just as you did in your question; maybe begin by just posting the entire HTML page (no need to post the CSS, as it does not seem to have any impact on the issue)